# How to Load the JS Content of Hidden Div while page loading

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div which is Hiddeb like tab menu. Each tab has Js code but only the first one is loading. The hidden tabs are not loading. I search all but I cannot find the working answer for my case. I want all hidden ul should load at the time of loading of page and for user it should only the first menu:

```
<ul id="core"> //Only this is visible
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>
<ul id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>    
<ul id="classics" class="hide">
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>

<style>
.hide = display:none;
</style
```

Comment: have you tried ajax? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: No I am not perfect in ajax.. could u suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

First make it as display:block.
And as soon as page is loaded make it "hide."

Like this .(Using jquery )

Html :

```
<ul id="core"> //Only this is visible
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>
<ul id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>    
<ul id="classics" class="hide">
     <li>
             Table here....
     </li>

<style>
.hide { display:block};
</style>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

  $(".hide").css("display","none");

});
```

Comment: Hello SeeTheC, I tried, but its not working. I put the function just below the body starting tag. and styles are on my stylesheet. Am I missed somthign ?

Comment: excately as u told. But its more then 1000 line code I cannot paste all here. Do I have to write something liek window.onload ??

Comment: @user2841252 : Can you give me the sample of js which is writen on any tab ?

Comment: its the js ( $(function(){
   $('#barchart').visualize({type: 'bar', height: '300px', width: '750px', appendTitle : true, lineWeight : 4, colors : ['#be1e2d','#666699','#92d5ea','#ee8310','#8d10ee','#5a3b16','#26a4ed','#f45a90','#e9e744']}).appendTo('#jQueryBarChart').trigger('visualizeRefresh');

  }); )    If I remove the class: hide its displaying in all tabs. But on first page load it showoing all tabs on front page, its means its not hiding.